# Python/Scrapy requests.get is very slow after few requests

Tags: python, scrapy

I dont know why, but for some reason, the request.get is very slow after a few requests on my gets.

I have requests.get for an url to get json informations from that site. It gives me only a json back, just simple.

But for any reason it requests like 5-20 times and than stops for like 3-4 seconds and than requests next. But why it stops so much times? Its very slow than...

My Parse in scrapy looks like that

```
 def parse(self, response):
        items = AmazonMobileDetailsItem()
        ...

        r = requests.get('https://www.URL.com/?get=json')
        result = r.json()
                new_list=[]
                for item in result['data']:

        ...
        yield item
```

Nothing special here, but for some reason the requests.get is very slow... i dont know why, all around 10 requests

Is there a limit or something to setup how much requests per second or something? I cannot find anything

Comment: How should we reproduce your problem?

Comment: It could be possible that the server has something like a limit on requests (per time interval).

Comment: @Peter But where i can check that...

Comment: @KlausD. I dont know! I dont know also why it comes... so i only ask if someone know if there is a problem

Comment: maybe reduce the waiting time for timeout and see if the server rejects you. If it‘s an API where you make a request, check the docs if possible

Comment: Is there a reason you are using requests inside of a scrapy spider? just yield a scrapy request to the url and in the callback function parse the json.

I have been forced to do something like this before, but only do it if you are forced. You should just follow the standard scrapy workflow if you can.